# How do I close my account on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, user-accounts, deleted-accounts

I accidentally allowed this website to share info from my Yahoo! account. I don't feel safe doing this. How do I delete this Stack Overflow account? I can't see an option to close/delete an account from the options.

Comment: And as for not feeling save: not too much information is shared. And when getting a different OpenID for use on these sites, see [How can I remove/change my second OpenId account?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21685/how-can-i-remove-change-my-second-openid-account)